# Yii linking breadcrumbs array links to javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

In my web application I need to link my breadcrumbs array links to  a javascript function which opens a dialog box. I tried but its not working.Anybody kindly help me with this since I am new to Yii.When I click the create  button It should go to the javascript function name "addStore"  which opens a dialog box for the view rendered.Any body kindly help me

The code I tried

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Store', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Store', 'url'=>array('create',array('onclick'=>"{addStore();$('#dialogStore').dialog('open')}"))),
);
```

Comment: Why are you using a breadcrumb menu in the first place? You have a regular menu here, so a `CMenu` would be the cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try [htmlOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs#htmlOptions-detail)?

```
$this->menu=array(
    array(
      'label'=>'List Store',
      'url'=>array('index')
      'htmlOptions' => array(
            'onclick' => "{addStore();$('#dialogStore').dialog('open')}",
       ),
   ),
```

and you can use [link attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs#links-detail) too.